# Splitting an IEnumerable<T> into an IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> without caching

Tags: c#

I'm wondering if it is possible to write a function that splits a sequence into sub-sequences returned as `IEnumerables`, where a sub-sequence ends if the current `T` is equal to the first `T` of that sub-sequence, **without caching the sub-sequence**. I've already managed to write an implementation which builds the current sub-sequence in a List.

So I'm hoping for an implementation of function

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitInSubsequences(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
   ... 
}
```

*without the use of some temporary collection `List<T>`* for caching the current sub-sequence.

To illustrate what the splitting operation should do:

```
var sequence = new List<int>{ 1,2,3,1,  4,6,1,5,4,  1,3,1, 2,2};
var subsequences = SplitInSubsequences( sequence ).ToList();
Assert.That(subsequences.Length,Is.EqualTo(4));
Assert.That(subsequences[0],Is.EquivalentTo(new List<int>{1,2,3,1});
Assert.That(subsequences[1],Is.EquivalentTo(new List<int>{4,6,6,5,4});
Assert.That(subsequences[2],Is.EquivalentTo(new List<int>{1,3,1});
Assert.That(subsequences[3],Is.EquivalentTo(new List<int>{2,2});
```

Note that in principle only the first element of each subsequence would need to be stored for comparison with the current element.

Comment: Should we be *smart* and not use *greedy* approach? `{1, 2, 1, 7, 1  4, 8, 9, 4}` - note that we have to skip `1`: `{1, 2, 1, 7, 1}` and `{4, 8, 9, 4}`.

Comment: GroupBy does such things but you need a condition for that

Comment: @DmitryBychenko no, I use ints here as an example but this is meant for splitting a sequence of coordinates in LinearRing coordinates, where a ring is terminated by a coordinate equal to the first coordinate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As is pretty much always the case, when you want to stream an `IEnumerable<T>` you should use an iterator block.  If you want nested streams, just nest your iterator blocks.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitInSubsequences<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    comparer ??= EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    using IEnumerator<T> iterator = sequence.GetEnumerator();
    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        T startOfGroup = iterator.Current;
        yield return NextGroup();

        IEnumerable<T> NextGroup()
        {
            yield return startOfGroup;

            while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return iterator.Current;

                if (comparer.Equals(iterator.Current, startOfGroup))
                {
                    yield break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just going to suggest controlling the iterator manually!

Comment: @Charlieface It's almost certainly an irrelevant change, but technically the code here would perform better.  As is, it's merely accessing a field of an object, with that change you'd be copying that field into a parameter, adding extra work when the variable could just be accessed directly.

Answer (score 3):

> only the first element of each subsequence would need to be stored for comparison with the current element.

This should meet that goal:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitInSubsequences<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    //local function
    IEnumerable<T> Internal(IEnumerator<T> inner, T endValue)
    {
        yield return inner.Current;
        bool okay;
        while ( (okay = inner.MoveNext()) && !endValue.Equals(inner.Current))
        {
            yield return inner.Current;
        }           
        if (okay) yield return inner.Current;   
    }
                 
    using var e = sequence.GetEnumerator();
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        var seqStart = e.Current;
        yield return Internal(e, seqStart);
    }
}
```

See it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/3FLTaZ

Comment: Disposing of the enumerator is important, and your equality check doesn't support null values.

Comment: Good points. Should be a little better now. Still a potential for `null`, but I'd hope that's not allowed as a sequence boundary.

Comment: Also if you're going to use a local method, you might as well just use the local variables already in scope; no need to pass them in.  The only reason to pass them in is if you want the method to not be local.

Comment: Supporting any value, and not excluding null values, is as simple as using the static equals method (or using a proper comparer as seen in my answer).  You gain basically nothing by adding the restriction.

Comment: @Servy I find it easier to build this with a separate method, and then convert it to local. Arguments are a side-effect of that process.